# Public and private field of model in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a data model `Event` with

- `Public Field`, means there are sharing with many users. For example, `title`, `start` and so on.
- `Private Field`, means there are specific for each user. For example, `reminder` since some users will set reminder for this event, some users will not.

How to design this model? One solution could be:

- `Public Field Event model`, only contains `Public Field`
- `Private Field Event model`, only contains `Private Field`
- Connect `Public Field Event model` and `Private Field Event model` with One-Many Relationship

I'm using `ViewSets` to support all APIs:

- If a user want to change `Public Field`, then come with `Public Field Event model`
- If a user want to change `Private Field`, then come with `Private Field Event model`
- If a user want to change `Public Field` and `Private Field` at the same time, how to support with `ViewSets` ?

Comment: I think you need better terminology, perhaps Event vs. Appointment?

Comment: Appointment? what do you mean? it's just a user want to set a reminder for a public event

Comment: An Event is something that happens (time/place/duration), while an Appointment is a user attending an event. Event = public, Appointment = private in your terminology. An Appointment would have a reminder.  I'm not sure it would make sense for a user to change both Appointment data and Event data at the same time.

Comment: I think you're design mostly works. The only big question seems to be if they want to change the public and private field at the same time.  In that case, why can't you just send two different writes to the backend for the two separate types of models?

Comment: You could have your viewset chose between two serializers based on the user id --- one for the user who can modify the model and a read-only one for everyone else.

Comment: You probably want a single `Event` model, but also other models for the private things (like `EventReminder`, containing a foreign key between a user and an event). Unfortunately this is not a good question for Stack Overflow, as it's really broad right now.